# Stargazer VAR model summary

Tags: r, stargazer, vector-auto-regression

i have lots of trouble with the export of a vector autoregression model with R, more specifically with the Stargazer package.

```
Model1 <- VAR(v1, p = 7, type = "const", season = NULL, exog = NULL) 
sum <- summary(Model1)
sum
```

gives the desired output in the console which i cannot export.
[image]

When i try it with stargazer like this:
`stargazer(sum[["varresult"]], type = 'text', out="VarModel.html")`

i get the error message

"Error in .summary.object$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Can someone help me out here please?

Comment: You gave stargazer an atomic vector. It needs a list.

Comment: When i run this line: stargazer(Model1[["varresult"]], type = 'text', out="VarModel.html") it gives me the model output, which is somehow a list, but the summary is not possible? how can i convert? Can you provide more details please?

Comment: `sum` is an R function. It has nothing to do with `summary`.  The `sum` function operates on numeric vectors and returns a length-1 numeric vector.

Comment: the model summary object is just named "sum" i can also name it "elephants", that does change nothing.

Comment: Except whatever it was (which you apparently have not examined with any of the available inspection tools) did NOT have a list structure. That is what the error was telling you.